# DataGridViewComboBox and Gridview

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a GridView and I have one column DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.
But when I assign my DataSource to the Grid I get this error:

**DataGridView Default Error Dialog**

The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:

```
System.FormatException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
```

To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

**OK**

I don't see why this is..

This is my first class:

```
    public class FloraItem
    {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Price { get; set; }
       public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
       public Category CategoryItem { get; set; }
    }
```

This class is the DataSource of the grid

The Category class looks like:

```
   public class Category
   {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool AddBreaksToPrint { get; set; }
   }
```

The Datasource of the dropdown (combobox) in the grid have the Category Datasource..

This is the InitializeComponent function

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.grdFloraItems = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.floraItemBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        this.categoryBindingSource2 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        this.lstCategories = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.priceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.expirationDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.CategoryItem = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.grdFloraItems)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.floraItemBindingSource)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.categoryBindingSource2)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // grdFloraItems
        // 
        this.grdFloraItems.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.grdFloraItems.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.grdFloraItems.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.grdFloraItems.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.priceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.expirationDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.CategoryItem});
        this.grdFloraItems.DataSource = this.floraItemBindingSource;
        this.grdFloraItems.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 55);
        this.grdFloraItems.Name = "grdFloraItems";
        this.grdFloraItems.ReadOnly = true;
        this.grdFloraItems.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(652, 206);
        this.grdFloraItems.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // floraItemBindingSource
        // 
        this.floraItemBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Data.FloraItem);
        // 
        // categoryBindingSource2
        // 
        this.categoryBindingSource2.DataSource = typeof(Data.Category);
        // 
        // nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
        this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Artikel";
        this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 250;
        // 
        // priceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.priceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Price";
        this.priceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Prijs";
        this.priceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "priceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.priceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // expirationDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.expirationDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ExpirationDate";
        this.expirationDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Verloop datum";
        this.expirationDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "expirationDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.expirationDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        this.expirationDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 150;
        // 
        // CategoryItem
        // 
        this.CategoryItem.DataPropertyName = "CategoryItem";
        this.CategoryItem.DataSource = this.categoryBindingSource2;
        this.CategoryItem.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.CategoryItem.HeaderText = "Categorie";
        this.CategoryItem.Name = "CategoryItem";
        this.CategoryItem.ReadOnly = true;
        this.CategoryItem.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.CategoryItem.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
        this.CategoryItem.ValueMember = "Id";
        // 
        // EditFloraItem
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(696, 273);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lstCategories);
        this.Controls.Add(this.grdFloraItems);
        this.Name = "EditFloraItem";
        this.Text = "EditFloraItem";
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.grdFloraItems, 0);
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.lstCategories, 0);
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.label1, 0);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.grdFloraItems)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.floraItemBindingSource)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.categoryBindingSource2)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.categoryBindingSource1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.categoryBindingSource)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

      }
```

This is where i'm stuck..

Answer (score 0):

Category needs to be a collection (like a List) not a single item.
And you would probably call is Categories.

Comment: you mean in the FloraItem class? (so that one should have a List<Category> CategoryItem {get; set; }).

Comment: Yes but I would call it CategoryItems.  A ComboBox needs to bind to a collection.